# How can I extract the text elements using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, class, xpath

Consider:

[image]

I am using Selenium to scrape the contents from the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)): https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bank-of-america-private-bank/id1096813830

I tried to extract the text field "As subject matter experts, our team is very engaging..."

I tried to find elements by class

```
review_ratings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('we-truncate we-truncate--multi-line we-truncate--interactive ember-view we-customer-review__body')
review_ratingsList = []
for e in review_ratings:
review_ratingsList.append(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
review_ratings
```

But it returns an empty list `[]`.

Is anything wrong with the code? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Re *"Is anything wrong with the code?"*: Yes, doesn't even compile (or whatever the equivalent is in Python):  `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: Related: *[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and wait for `presence_of_all_elements_located` and use the following CSS selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bank-of-america-private-bank/id1096813830")
review_ratings = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.we-customer-review__body p[dir="ltr"]')))
review_ratingsList = []
for e in review_ratings:
    review_ratingsList.append(e.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
print(review_ratingsList)
```

### Output:

```
['As subject matter experts, our team is very engaging and focused on our near and long term financial health!', 'Very much seems to be an unfinished app. Can’t find secure message alert. Or any alerts for that matter. Most of my client team is missing from the “send to” list. I have other functions very useful, when away from my computer.']
```

Comment: May I ask what does the ".we-customer-review__body" do? @KunduK

Comment: It is class name.For css selector classname starts with .classname

Answer (score 5):

Using [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bank-of-america-private-bank/id1096813830'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
item = soup.select_one("blockquote > p").text
print(item)
```

Output:

```
As subject matter experts, our team is very engaging and focused on our near and long term financial health!
```

Comment: I like this answer as if you have a list of URLs this is I imagine the quickest approach to go to the specific pages and scrape them. If navigation between pages is needed then this would not work.

Comment: Glad to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait for visibility of an element and get the text. Please check [good Selenium locator](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
review_ratings = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".we-customer-review")))
for review_rating in review_ratings:
    starts = review_rating.find_element_by_css_selector(".we-star-rating").get_attribute("aria-label")
    title = review_rating.find_element_by_css_selector("h3").text
    review = review_rating.find_element_by_css_selector("p").text
```

Answer (score 3):

Mix Selenium with [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)).

Using [WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/bank-of-america-private-bank/id1096813830"
browser.get(url)
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

bs = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')

bs.blockquote.p.text
```

Output:

```
Out[22]: 'As subject matter experts, our team is very engaging and focused on our near and long term financial health!'
```

Comment: @Juan C what ""return document.body.innerHTML"" does? thank you

Comment: AFAIK, it lets you get the HTML code of a dynamic HTML webpage after everything loads. If you try to get the  `BeautifulSoup` object from the raw link it won't have the data of javascript objects that have to load and the like. (I don't come from a software engineering background, so my language might be inaccurate).

Comment: @ArthurMorgan if you find it is the best answer could you please mark it so your question doesn't appear in the unanswered questions page ?